# Can't use trait on function pointer

Tags: rust

When I try to call a trait method on a function pointer:

```
trait Foo {
    fn do_it(&self, i: i32);
}

impl Foo for fn(i32) {
    fn do_it(&self, i: i32) {
        self(i)
    }
}

fn bar(i: i32) {}
fn baz() {
    bar.do_it(7);
}
```

The compiler says `no method named 'do_it' found for fn item 'fn(i32) {bar}' in the current scope ... note: 'Foo' defines an item 'do_it', perhaps you need to implement it`.

What's wrong with my implementation?

Answer (score 2):

You need to impl `Foo` on a trait object, instead of trying to access the `fn()` type. By declaring that you want to implement `Foo` for any object `F` which has already implemented the `Fn(i32)` trait, the compiler then recognizes that there is a method associated with that type of function.

I added `main()` to be able to view output and verify it worked as expected.

```rust
trait Foo {
    fn do_it(&self, i: i32);
}

impl<F> Foo for F where F: Fn(i32) {
    fn do_it(&self, i: i32) {
        self(i)
    }
}

fn bar(i: i32) {
    println!("{}", i);
}

fn main() {
    bar.do_it(7);
}
```

Comment: "You need to impl Foo on a trait object" - they don't, and that's not what you do in your own code - there's no `dyn Fn` here. This is so-called "blanket implementation" - https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-02-traits.html#using-trait-bounds-to-conditionally-implement-methods.

Comment: Using a blanket implementation prevents me from implementing the trait on more than one type of function pointer, since they conflict.

Comment: Yeah, that may just be a limitation of Rust's strong typing... you'd need to repeat your impl block for every type, the same way you'd need to repeat an impl for every int type (i8, u8, i16...), although it probably could be shortened with a macro.